# I am getting this error on visual studio code under the Terminal tab - bash: command not found on visual code Terminal

Tags: react-select

this is the error:

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
MacBook-Air:React malune$ sytem_info
bash: sytem_info: command not found
MacBook-Air:React malune$

I am trying to run some files under the folders in visual studio code:
files like: App.js,App.test.js,index.js,()package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the default shell to be set to zsh as default. From your Users & Preferences settings in Mac. In order to do that

Close your current terminal VS Code instance

From Users & Groups preferences

Choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, then click Users & Groups.

Click the lock , then enter your account name and password.

Control-click your user name in the list of users on the left, then choose Advanced Options.

Choose a shell from the ”Login shell” menu, then click OK to save the changes.

Go to reopen Visual Studio Code or terminal and check if you can run any command

For further references and check how to use a different shell without changing the default visit

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208050

[image]