# Is there anyway to delete these extra lines in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I just want to see the output without these lines; Because it distracts me. [image]

Comment: [macos terminal "the default interactive shell is now zsh" visual studio](https://www.google.com/search?q=macos+terminal+%22the+defalt+interactive+shell+is+now+zsh%22+visual+studiop&oq=macos+terminal+%22the+defalt+interactive+shell+is+now+zsh%22+visual+studiop&aqs=chrome..69i57.38866j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has some suggestions

Comment: [I am getting this error on visual studio code under the Terminal tab - bash: command not found on visual code Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60256826/i-am-getting-this-error-on-visual-studio-code-under-the-terminal-tab-bash-com)

Comment: Try Shift+Command+P -> Terminal: Select Default Terminal then select zsh

Comment: Also did you actually try to run the command to change the shell that the message suggested?

Comment: Thank you to both of you,  I used  @PaulSamsotha method and fixed few things. No I didn't change the shell or anything !!

Comment: Now there are still two lines from the top and the last line, is there anyway to make it disappear so I can just focus on the outputs ?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension. After installation, your run button has three options.

[image]

Select `Run Code`, and the code result will be output in the `OUTPUT` window (only the result, no other lines). Selecting `Run Java` will output the result in the original terminal, and `Debug Java` will start code debugging.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: yes it worked thank you, but there is a problem I can't put any input at this extension, Do you know any solution to solve this problem ? https://ibb.co/wLK37fV

Comment: ok I solve this problem https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/891 But again it prints useless lines 3 from above and 1 from below @JialeDu

Comment: Please try to configure the following two lines in `setting.json`, 
`"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true`,`"code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false`.
hope this will solve your problem.